# Where is the striping error?

Tags: rdf, jena

I am trying to work with the [RDF dump of DBLP](http://sw.deri.org/~aharth/2004/07/dblp/dblp-2006-02-06.rdf), available from [DBLP in RDF](http://sw.deri.org/~aharth/2004/07/dblp/). I attempted to use [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/)'s [rdfcat](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/jena/rdfcat.html) to convert that file to into [Turtle format](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/):

```
rdfcat -x dblp-2006-02-06.rdf -out t > dblp.ttl
```

Unfortunately, this aborts with the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 378, col:
147] {E202} Expecting XML start or end element(s). String data "
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????" not allowed.
 Maybe a striping error.
        at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.error
(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:128)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML$ErrorHandlerBridge.error(LangRDF
XML.java:246)
…
```

As far as I could learn from another question, [What is a striping error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188220/1281433), a *striping error* occurs in RDF/XML parsing when the hierarchical XML structure does not conform to RDF/XML's even/odd rule. Now, looking into that file, the respective part of the file looks like this:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/journals/ac/ac40.html#YousifTD95"><dc:identifier>journals/ac/YousifTD95</dc:identifier><dc:date>2002-01-03</dc:date><rdf:type rdf:resource="http://sw.deri.org/~aharth/2004/07/dblp/dblp.owl#Article"/>
<dc:creator><foaf:Person rdf:nodeID="MazinSYousif"><foaf:name>Mazin S. Yousif</foaf:name></foaf:Person></dc:creator>
<dc:creator><foaf:Person rdf:nodeID="MatthewThazhuthaveetil"><foaf:name>Matthew Thazhuthaveetil</foaf:name></foaf:Person></dc:creator>
<dc:creator><foaf:Person rdf:nodeID="ChitaRDas"><foaf:name>Chita R. Das</foaf:name></foaf:Person></dc:creator>
<dc:title rdf:parseType="Literal">Cache Coherence in Multiprocessors: A Survey.</dc:title>
<pages>127-179</pages>
<year>1995</year>
<volume>40</volume>
<journal>Advances in Computers</journal>
</rdf:Description>
```

Line 378 seems to be the one with *Matthew Thazhuthaveetil*, according to Nano. However, somehow, I fail to see where that line could be structurally problematic (in particular when comparing that line to other lines around). Is there really a structural problem there (and if so, what is it), or is the error message misleading?

Comment: The line has only 135 chars, not 147. It could be that just the formatting is different in your snippet here but you could have a look whether there are by any chance some unprintable characters (other than normal whitespace) on that line.

Comment: @jkbkot: Hm, true ... looking again, Nano even tells me explicitly that the line indeed has only 135 chars. A hex editor is showing no invisible characters at the end of the line other than a single linefeed, like at the end of the other lines.

Comment: You may need to look farther back, too.  Is this all nested _within_ some other XML content? If you're at the wrong "depth", then the elements that should be resources may be treated as properties, and vice versa.  This would be a problem…

Comment: Notice that the [DBLP in RDF](http://sw.deri.org/~aharth/2004/07/dblp/) page that you linked to says "An XML dump of the data is available. There is a (possibly buggy) XML Style Sheet (XSLT) that transforms the XML file into an RDF/XML file (you need a machine with several GB of main memory to perform the conversion)."  Is is possible you're running into such a bug?

Comment: Not an answer on why this error occurs in Jena, but I just ran the DBLP RDF/XML file to which you link through Sesame's RDF verification tool and it parses fine there. I managed to convert to Turtle format using the [RDFConvert commandline tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rdfconvert/) too.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I don't think it is nested within anything it shouldn't be nested in; I looked at the file in [Xml Explorer](http://xmlexplorer.codeplex.com/) (displays the hierarchy in a tree view) and I couldn't see any structural difference to the nodes before (so the error should have occurred there already). As for the remark about the bugs, it is very well possible that I am encountering (the result of) such a bug, but to fix that bug, I need to know what the problem in the resulting file is :-/

Comment: I've downloaded the first megabyte of the file, truncated it, adding in `</rdf:RDF>` at an appropriate place, and the file (including the line in question) parses fine for me using [RDF::Trine](https://metacpan.org/pod/RDF::Trine). Perhaps a Jena bug?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra: Interesting, that's true. Seems to work without any error for me, as well. However, when trying to import that into Fuseki, I am getting `Error 400: Parse error: [line: 1101736, col: 58] Broken IRI (bad character: '<'): http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(19960115)17:1` with the resulting TTL file.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra: That appears to be a bug in that RDFConvert tool you linked to: In the RDF/XML file, the original string is `rdf:about="http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(19960115)17:1&lt;42::AID-JCC4&gt;3.0.CO;2-0"`. While RDFConvert correctly escapes `&gt;` as `\>` for the resulting Turtle document, the `&lt;` is written as `<` rather than `\u003C`, thereby creating what Fuseki recognizes as a Turtle syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this myself with apache jena 2.11.1 and it was fine. Have you tried `riot --validate'?

The error is curious:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 378, col:
147] {E202} Expecting XML start or end element(s). String data "
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????" not allowed.
Maybe a striping error.
```

It's not showing printable characters, which is mysterious.

The error simply means that the rdf contains non-whitespace characters outside a property tag. That suggests it might have invisible junk, perhaps trailing after the `</dc:creator>`?

I don't see anything like that, so it really feels like an IO error somewhere.

Comment: `riot --validate` does not show any such error, and when trying `rdfcat` again as described in the question, it runs a lot longer before it eventually fails due to an `OutOfMemoryException`. So, indeed, must have been an IO error of some sort.

Comment: If you use the `riot` command (no validation option) it will output n-triples without eating memory. If you really need turtle, try loading into tdb then output turtle (although n-triples is a subset of turtle).

Comment: Well, I'm trying to keep file size small, and while the equivalent Turtle file is about 580 MB in size, the respective N-Triples file is over 1.5 GB in size.

Comment: gzip! I think jena handles gzipped rdf files automatically, and the CPU overhead isn't huge.